# Salvar texto duma objecto tkinter Text numa variável

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira para salvar o conteúdo textual dum objecto `tkinter.Text` numa variável string.

Porquê? Porque creio o objecto tkinter.Text dentro duma função, e portanto não é visível a outra função que manipula o texto do objecto tkinter.Text.

Eu sei que com o método `get` posso recuperar o texto do objecto no escopo deste ultimo.

```
def manipulateText():
    # Gostaria de manipular o texto do objecto `textArea`,
    # mas textArea não é visível aqui.
    # Se textArea fosse do tipo `Entry`
    # eu poderia salvar o texto numa variável do tipo tkinter.StringVar()
    # mas tkinter.Text não fornece esta possibilidade.

def func():
    win = tkinter.Tk()
    textArea = tkinter.Text(win)
    textArea.pack()
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Eu não entendi sua pergunta. Poderia exemplificar com um código? Em outras palavras, se você já sabe como pegar o texto do widget, qual é a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 1):

Não seria simplesmente o caso de declarar `textarea` no escopo superior? (i.e. na classe ou módulo)

```
textarea = None

def manipulateText():
    # Lê o texto
    texto = textarea.get(1.0, END)
    # Insere mais texto
    textarea.insert(END, "hello, world")
    # Etc

def func():
    win = tkinter.Tk()
    textArea = tkinter.Text(win)
    textArea.pack()
    win.mainloop()
```